# Using OpenSSH config file with -addext and -subj parameters

Tags: bash, ssl, certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to create a bash script to manage a PKI. I want to use OpenSSL conf file to specify some parameters for the generated and signed certs using my CA.

I specified default parameters as below:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca = my ca

[ my ca ]
dir            = "path/to/ca"                     
certs          = $dir/certs                             
crl_dir        = $dir/crl                               
new_certs_dir  = $dir/new_certs                         
database       = $dir/index.txt                         
serial         = $dir/serial.txt                      

private_key    = $dir/ca.key    
certificate    = $dir/ca.crt      

default_days   = 3650               
default_crl_days = 30         
default_md     = sha256             

policy         = policy_strict      

[ policy_strict ]
countryName             = match
stateOrProvinceName     = match
organizationName        = match
organizationalUnitName  = supplied
commonName              = supplied
emailAddress            = optional

[ req ]
default_bits            = 2048
prompt                  = no
string_mask             = utf8only
default_md              = sha256
req_extensions          = v3_req
distinguished_name      = dn
default_days            = 365       

[ dn ]
C               = *my countrycode*
ST              = *my country*
L               = *my city*
O               = *my name
emailAddress    = *my mail*

[ v3_req ]
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
basicConstraints        = critical, CA:true
keyUsage                = critical, digitalSignature, cRLSign, keyCertSign
subjectAltName          = @alt_names

[ ecparam ]
namedCurve      = secp384r1

[ alt_names ]
email         = *my mail*
```

I want to specify the Common Name, Organization Unit and alt_names DNS entry during the cert generation with the script using variables set by the user at script run time.

However, when generating the signing request as below:

```bash
openssl req -x509 -newkey ec:secp384r1 -keyout path/to/key -out path/to/cert --subj "/CN=$fqdn/OU=$ou" -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:$fqdn"
```

the `-subj` and `-addext` parameters are not used by OpenSSL, overriding with values set on the config file (and those being not set in the config file, the CSR therefore doesn't have any CN/OU/subjectAltName DNS set).

Is there a way to combine the command line arguments with the config file, specifically for the OU, CN and SAN values to be set in the script ?

Thanks

Comment: `openssl req -x509 -new[key] ...` generates a self-signed cert (as your `path/to/cert` suggests) not a "signing request" or "CSR". Such a cert _cannot_ "us[e] my CA". `req -new[key] -x509` does not use a config section designated by `req_extensions` like you have, but instead one designated by `x509_extensions`; in the upstream 'standard' config this is `[v3_ca]` not `[v3_req]`. But I cannot reproduce; with both 1.1.1 and 3.0 `-subj` (only one hyphen needed) and `-addext` DO override (the latter per extension) the (corrected) config file. ...

Comment: ... However you don't need to use the commandline options; an alternative is to have the shell variable(s) exported as environment variable(s), and OpenSSL's config file can use environment variable(s); see the man page.